Bevel Or Smooth - Sliced Sphere

I am trying to re-create a car lens.
Have Sliced into a Sphere and 2 Cylinders to create the object - and want the sliced edges to blend as smoothly as possible without showing the creases.
As the round objects have multiple subdivides - it's messing up the smoothness of the circles.
If I create the shape with limited subdivides, it only creates a rough version of what is required, outcome-wise.
Have tried all the tools in the bag to no joy, as the shapes are so complex - any help is appreciated!






Hello could you please show different pictures of the object?

Attached "moonboots" - It's hard to explain with pictures, but to touch, there are no creases to feel (super smooth) - thanks

Maybe try this, create a UV sphere, remove a big part of it:

Cut this edge with the knife:

Remove some vertices:

Extrude and flatten:

Bevel this edge:


I think you are absolutely right @moonboots - I can't thank you enough for your time and advice...Gold Star!
